# Using SOAP web services.. app doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, xml, soap

I am following [this tutorial to use SOAP web services](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/). 
At first it presented some problems but after doing a few things (mentioned in the comments on the tutorial), it started working, but it is not working properly.
The problem is that after adding the input in the edit text, when i click on the corresponding number to convert the temperature, it does not do anything. 
I am pasting the code below, [This is an external link for LogCat](http://pastebin.com/Ap9NwhSS) (of pastebin.com, where I am pasting the **logcat**) since adding it here exceeds the permissible length of the question
.
Any hint/help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

LAYOUT:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/editText1">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textView2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/editText2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/btnFar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/btnCel" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnClear" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CODE:-

```
package com.webservice;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebServiceDemoActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
      private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
      private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
      private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
      private static String METHOD_NAME2 = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
      private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

      Button btnFar,btnCel,btnClear;
      EditText txtFar,txtCel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service_demo);

        btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);
        btnCel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCel);
        btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
        txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

        btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                        //Initialize soap request + add parameters
                  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);       

                  //Use this to add parameters
                  request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

                  //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                  envelope.dotNet = true;

                  try {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                        if(result != null)
                        {
                              //Get the first property and change the label text
                              txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  }
            });

        btnCel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                        //Initialize soap request + add parameters
                  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);       

                  //Use this to add parameters
                  request.addProperty("Celsius",txtCel.getText().toString());

                  //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                  envelope.dotNet = true;

                  try {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);

                        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                        if(result != null)
                        {
                              //Get the first property and change the label text
                              txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  }
            });

        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                        txtCel.setText("");
                        txtFar.setText("");
                  }
            });
    }
}
```

STRINGS RESOURCE:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Using SOAP Test 2</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    <string name= "textView1">Fahrenheit</string>
    <string name="editText1">0</string>
    <string name= "textView2">Celsius</string>
    <string name="editText2">0</string>
    <string name="btnFar">Convert to Celsius</string>
    <string name="btnCel">Convert to Fahrenheit</string>
    <string name="btnClear">Clear</string>

</resources>
```

MANIFEST FILE:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.webservice.WebServiceDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exception you are getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
```

To resolve this problem, you need to copy the `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar` to the `/libs` folder of your project then rebuild the project. Then Eclipse ADT will automatically add this jar to the buildpath of your project.

Comment: I had learnt how to add an external jar from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary). I did add the jar file by following the steps. 
I just also manually copied the file to /libs folder. It has not helped.
I have ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar

Comment: I just downloaded ksoap2-j2se-full-2.6.0- jar-with-dependencies.jar. Adding this resulted in errors not visible in my code.

Comment: I just downloaded and used ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.2/#2.6.2%253Fstate%253Dclosed). Now again it doesn't run, and rather says that my project contains errors. The LogCat can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/VLLDrage). Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same tutorial.

This worked for me: i have changed

```
  private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
  private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
  private static String NAMESPACE    = "http://tempuri.org/";
```

with

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String NAMESPACE    = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
```

For finding the correct name space, you have to browse the web service URL. In this case: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL. Then, you can find the correct name space at targetNamespace="........"